# How do I tell Chromium to save a torrent file instead of starting Transmission?

Tags: chromium, transmission, bittorrent

When I donload a torrent file in chromium, it starts with transmission. But I want it to save on downloads folder. Where can I configure it? I am on natty

Answer (score 1):

According to the Arch wiki chromium uses xdg-open to select what will open a file.  You could right click and save as, or immediately pause it in transmission and pull it out of `~/.config/transmission/torrents`.

If you remove the mime-type it uses, it won't open properly without an open-with or file->open on your desktop.